# Page.call not being processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller with page.call calls to my javascript functions. That normally works just fine. However, on one of our servers the page calls are being totally ignored. Same code but it works on most but not on one. It is not a production/development issue as it works on the 32-bit production server and not on the 64-bit production server.

Everything else works just fine, but the page.call and page.alert calls just don't do anything. No javascript errors (javascript is on and is working), nothing in the log file, nothing. The calls are just ignored.

So...

Is there a setting to turn RJS on and off? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this thing happen when the javascript function accepts an array of strings, and one of the values contains international characters.   It works if the data doesn't have wierd characters in it...

haven't found the solution to that, but your problem sounded similar to mine, and maybe you have something similar?

in ruby:

```
def view
   some_array = Array.new
   some_array.push("Información")
   render :update do |page|
        page.call("myFunc", some_array)
   end
end
```

javascript in the page:

```
function myFunc(stuff)
{
    //never gets here when international chars are present in "stuff"
}
```